# Django: Access Admin User in Python Shell

Tags: python, django, profile

I am using Django Userena, but when trying to login to the django admin screen userena is creating a fuss: `Profile matching query does not exist`.

How can I create a profile for the admin user using the shell? Here is my Profile model, but I don't know how to access the key for the admin user to create a Profile object for it:

```
class Profile(UserenaBaseProfile, FacebookProfileModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    website = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I know this is probably pretty simple, but google has failed me so far... Thanks for your ideas!

PS. I used to be able to login to my admin screen without issue, but something has changed now and I am getting the `Profile matching query does not exist` error (I didn't change the code, either).. Any ideas why I can't login now are also appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
> from <profile_package>.models import Profile
> user = User.objects.get(username='<admin_user_name>')
> profile = Profile(user=user)
> profile.save()
```

Comment: Please be advised that this has been deprecated as of django 1.9: Using this method will get: AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'user.User'. Instead use: `from django.apps import apps`
 `User = apps.get_model('user', 'User')`. and then continue.

Comment: This is also helpful when creating mezzanine profiles on a site that already has users without them.