# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/ User has no scuser

Tags: python, django

I have another site that I created which does not have this problem and is to the best of my knowledge setup the same way.

Here is my models.py from the users app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.choices import *
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from listings.models import University

# Create your models here.

class SCUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,default='User')
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    university = models.ForeignKey(University,related_name='u_university',null=False,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        SCUser.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.scuser.save()
```

Here is the error:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/
User has no scuser.
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 393, in login
    return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 90, in dispatch
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 183, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 119, in form_valid
    auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 160, in login
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 25, in update_last_login
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 80, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 807, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 847, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/Users/garrettlove/Documents/Student-Cribz/Website/newsite/users/models.py", line 29, in save_user_profile
    instance.scuser.save()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 407, in __get__
    self.related.get_accessor_name()
django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no scuser.
```

I have looked around and can't seem to find anything relevant on this as I aready create the proper instances when a new user is created. If you need to see any other parts of the project let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you already have users in the app.  Easiest option would be to update those users using `get_or_create()`.

```
for user in User.objects.all():
UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

You can do in the shell, run in a migration or drop the DB (if in new dev) and start from there.

Comment: What if the site is live?

Comment: So i would just type in `python` and then enter those two lines or something else?

Comment: If live you'd need to either do it in a migration or run it in the shell.  You should not run into the issue once in place and new user creation auto creates the profile with user creation.

Comment: How do I do it in a migration

Comment: in the Python shell, you'd import the required objects, then the code for user in User.objects.all():
SCUser.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

Comment: I just did `import User` and it said no module etc.

Comment: For Migration - Follow the documents - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Comment: To help with imports, follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620783/django-access-admin-user-in-python-shell

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    
    def __str(self):
       return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.profile.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).